# better understanding of jquery with enquire.js

Tags: jquery, object, enquire.js

I'm currently trying to improve my overall understanding of jQuery and have a problem that I think will help me achieve that. I'm looking into [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js) to enhance a responsive site.

Here's the (simplified) html for a small section detailing the services of a company:

```
<section id="services">
  <article id="services-coaching" class="closed">
    <div class="image">
      <?php include("library/images/service-coaching.svg"); ?>
      <div class="fallback">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article id="services-workshops" class="closed">
    <div class="image">
      <?php include("library/images/service-workshops.svg"); ?>
      <div class="fallback">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article id="services-courses" class="closed">
    <div class="image">
      <?php include("library/images/service-courses.svg"); ?>
      <div class="fallback">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

jQuery for screens **smaller than** 47em:

```
// Services - mobile
    $('#services-coaching, #services-workshops, #services-courses').waypoint(function(direction) {
        if (direction === 'down') {
          $(this).addClass('open').removeClass('closed');
        }
        else {
          $(this).addClass('closed').removeClass('open');
        }
    }, { offset: 100 });
```

Here I'm using waypoint.js to trigger a CSS transition on an SVG image by changing the class - everything is done progressively with CSS.

For larger screens the CSS hide's the text (`.text`) on `.closed` and reveals it when the `article` is clicked (changing the class to `.open`) as well as triggering the animations.

```
// Services - large screen 
$('#services article').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('open').removeClass('closed');
});
```

This is where my understanding of jQuery needs improving! I know that I can use these jQuery objects with enquire.js to essentially match and unmatch them depending on screen size, something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 47.0625em)", function() {

    match : function() {
        // enable 'waypoint' jQuery object
        // disable 'click' jQuery object
    },
    unmatch : function() {
        // disable 'waypoint' jQuery object
        // enable 'click' jQuery object
    }

  });

});
```

But I don't know how to best create the objects so that they can be used in this way. 
I started looking [into jQuery fundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/javascript-basics) but it has not helped me :(

**UPDATE:**
<strike>Trying but failing</strike>

Thought `.bind` / `.unbind` might work. Tested this on the click event initially but <strike>doesn't work</strike> *I was doing it wrong*. Following works for click:

```
enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 47.0625em)", {
  match : function() {
    $('#services article').bind('click', function() {
      $(this).addClass('open').removeClass('closed');
    });    
  },
  unmatch : function () {
    $('#services article').unbind('click');
  }
});
```

Getting there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I haven't improved my understanding of jQuery objects and functions as I'd have liked, but I have got this particular problem solved and working.

My main issue was that the 'waypoint' and 'click' functions were both active once the window was resized. I knew the solution was to cancel out each one where it was not required but I didn't know how to do it. I do now…

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  enquire.register("screen and (max-width: 47em)", {

    match : function() {
      $('#services-coaching, #services-workshops, #services-courses').waypoint(function(direction) {
          if (direction === 'down') {
            $(this).addClass('open').removeClass('closed');
          }
          else {
            $(this).addClass('closed').removeClass('open');
          }
      }, { offset: '50%' });
    },
    unmatch : function () {
      $('#services-coaching, #services-workshops, #services-courses').waypoint('destroy');
    }
  });

  enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 47.0625em)", {

    match : function() {
      $('#services article').removeClass('open');
      $('#services article').bind('click', function() {
        $(this).addClass('open').removeClass('closed');
      });
    },
    unmatch : function () {
      $('#services article').unbind('click');
    }

  });

});
```

`bind`/`unbind` click event and `waypoint('destroy')` did the trick! :D